# Ember.js computed property not waiting for asynchronous RSVP promise

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember.js component where I'm trying to use a computed property to determine its visibility based on the result of an asynchronous RSVP promise. However, it seems like the computed property is not waiting for the promise to resolve, resulting in the **count** object being undefined.

Here's an excerpt from my component code:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import RSVP from 'rsvp';

export default Component.extend({
    classNames: ['count'],
    countService: service('count'),

    getCount: computed(function () {
        debugger;
        RSVP.all([
            this.get('countService').getCount()
        ]).then(([count]) => {
            return Number(count);
        });
    }),

    isVisible: computed('getCount', function () {
        debugger;
        let count = this.get('getCount');
        return count !== undefined && count > 0;
    }),
});
```

As you can see, the **getCount** computed property is calling a method **getCount**() on the countService injected service. This method returns a promise that resolves with the count value.

In the **isVisible** computed property, I'm trying to access the **count** value returned by the **getCount** computed property. However, when I log the value of **count** during debugging, it shows up as **undefined**, even though the promise should have resolved by that point.

I'm not sure why the computed property is not waiting for the promise to resolve before trying to access the value. Am I missing something in my implementation? Is there a better way to handle asynchronous dependencies in Ember.js computed properties?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what ember-source version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Will you please try this once? I haven't tested but hope this makes sense.

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import RSVP from 'rsvp';

export default Component.extend({
  classNames: ['count'],
  countService: service('count'),

  getCount: computed(function() {
    return RSVP.all([this.get('countService').getCount()]).then(([count]) => {
      return Number(count);
    });
  }),

  isVisible: computed('getCount', function() {
    let count = this.get('getCount');
    return count !== undefined && count > 0;
  }),
});
```

Comment: Please don't post an answer if you haven't tested the code yourself. Only post an answer if you have a solution that works, that you understand and that you can explain well.

Answer (score 0):

Your computed property is not returning anything, hence you are getting undefined. The answer with return RSVP.all would also not work because you will be returning the promise and not the resolved value.

An alternative solution is to add property called 'count' to the component and when an event occurs which should trigger count change you can invoke a method to call your service/API and set the count value to the component. Eg:

```
setCount() {
   this.get('countService').getCount().then((count) => {
      this.count = Number(count);
    });
  }

isVisible: computed.gt('count',  0),
```

And then in your isVisible can be computed on 'count' instead of 'getCount' change. You could do same in the computed but I don't think that's the right use case for computed, I believe computed are not supposed to change state, for that we used to have observers, but they are not recommended as well and might have been deprecated by now - haven't used ember for quite some time now, bit short answer is do not use observer if possible. But hope this helps.